# Add EditText dynamically in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-edittext

I add an edittext to view on button click and then I want to be insert values ​​in the SQLite db. So far I have tried this code to the new EditText, but are created horizontally rather than vertically. Also how do I manage ContentValues ​​to insert the data of the EditText added?

```
public void Add(View v) {
      EditText et=new EditText(cnt);
      linear.addView(et);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For adding your edittext vertically to your layout, you can try following codes; I assumed you are using LinearLayout:

```
LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_layout_id);
LinearLayout dynamic_component = new LinearLayout(this);
dynamic_component.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
dynamic_component.addView(et);
root.addView(dynamic_component);
```

If I understood right, you can try following codes:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(YOU_KEY, text);
database.insert(YOUR_TABLE_NAME, null, values);
```

Comment: now as I insert the values ​​of the new EditText in the db?? I use this code to enter the value of the EditText that is created by default. I hope I explained ... thanks

`public void insertIntoDb(View v) {
            
      ContentValues cv = new ContentValues(7);
cv.put(FattureTable.IMPORTO_FATTURA, Importo.getText().toString());`

Comment: I updated my answer, but I am not sure whether I understood right. what do you mean by managing your contentvalues?

Comment: how to get the values ​​of the new EditText to insert them in the db??

Comment: I'll try your code, see my ContentValues​​, I get the value of the EditText that is displayed by default, so now I have to get the values ​​of the EditText that will be created.

Comment: Does it work? editText.getText().toString() should be working if you create the EditText in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Set the orientation of your parent view (here linear) to vertical in the xml file where your layout is.

Then you will be able to add EditText views vertically.

```
android:orientation="vertical"
<!--default is horizontal. -->
```

That is whay edittext added are aligning horizontally.